# How to enable plugin only for release build in Android Studio (KTS)?

Tags: android, build.gradle, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have following plugins in **build.gradle.kts** for **app module**:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.huawei.agconnect")
    id("kotlin-android")
}
```

I need to use **com.huawei.agconnect** only for **release**, because it slows down builds (I have to disable **org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache**, otherwise I am not able build app). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct way to enable plugins only for a specific build type. The solutions below may be helpful.

You can use the  afterEvaluate block to apply the plugin only in the broadcast configuration. For example:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
}
afterEvaluate {
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.contains("Release") }) {
        apply(plugin = "com.huawei.agconnect")
    }
}
```

You can use the buildTypes block to use the plugin only in the release configuration. For example:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.huawei.agconnect")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // enable the plugin for release build
            apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
        }
        debug {
            // disable the plugin for debug build
            com.huawei.agconnect.AGConnectPlugin.disable()
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the project.ext feature to activate the plugin only in the release configuration. For example:

```
    plugins {
        id("com.android.application")
        id("kotlin-android")
    }
    
    project.ext.set("agcEnabled", false)
    
    android {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // enable the plugin for release build
                project.ext.set("agcEnabled", true)
            }
        }
    }


if (project.ext.get("agcEnabled")) {
    apply(plugin = "com.huawei.agconnect")
}
```

Also the links below may help you.

[Supporting Multiple Flavors](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor-android-0000001057944603)

[Gradle configuration-cache fails](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201632054585410020)

[Configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html)

Comment: Thank you. It is strange, I tested all of them, none is working.
First gradle.startParameter.taskNames is empty, second com.huawei.agconnect.AGConnectPlugin.disable() unresolved reference, third is always true. I am using latest Android Studio Build #AI-231.9161.38.2311.10491752, built on July 13, 2023.